# Gpt-3 and Chomsky

Tags: artificial-intelligence, linguistics, chomsky

Why does Chomsky assert that GPT-3 is not a language model ? [video here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=c6MU5zQwtT4) at 1:12:00

Comment: Because by "model" he means a scientific model of human languages. GPT-3 applies just as well to artificial languages, or, really, any symbol generation sufficiently large sample of which can be produced. And it functions as an inscrutable black box that tells us nothing about the workings of a language, which is what scientific models are supposed to do.

Comment: If it were a [formal language model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy), then what type its grammar belongs to in his general four hierarchies?...